# Unity HDRP black screen on load

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering

I'm building a game for mac and windows with Unity HDRP, on mac it works fine, but on windows, only the canvas's are rendering, the rest of the game renders for half a second then goes black, Sorry about the minimal detail but I'm sending it to a friend to test so I have minimal information, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried on multiple different windows computers but they all have the same result, only the ui is rendering, other macs work fine
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XSAo.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPT2F.png

Comment: Enter the project setting section and place a screen shot from the **HDRP Setting** and **Quality** sections.

Comment: I've added the images to the original post

Comment: In the quality section, put  HDRP Asset in all graphics from low to ultra and see if it works or not.